# Protobuf - Multiple messages from the same class

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have the following message in a `proto` file

```
message User
required string name = 1;
required string password = 2;
```

- How can I differentiate multiple instances of the same message?
- If I wanted to serialize the registered users of an app for instance
- Is protobuf indicated for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiate multiple instances of the same message"? You can know if they are they same instance or not the normal Java way, using `==`; you can know if two instances have the same value using `equals`.

Comment: for example: i serialize a `User`. After that i serialize another `User`. After that i want to read them from the file. How do i read all of them? and how to i distinguish them?

Comment: Are you asking how to separate multiple protobuf messages in one input stream?

Comment: yes, and if they are from the same `message` how do i distinguish them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works with some additional coding. When protobuf reads a message from a stream it does not know the length of one message. It sees simply a stream of fields as name/value pairs and no indicator for start or end of a message.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques):

> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next begins. The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their own.

Google's implementations contains some helper classes for this usecase. Have a look at [CodedInputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.html) and [CodedOutputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.html).

One possible way for writing:

- serialize **one** object to a memory buffer
- use CodedOutputStream to write the length of the buffer as a single number to the output stream
- add the memory buffer containing your serialized object to the output stream
- proceed with the next object

One possible way for reading:

- use CodedInputStream to read one number from the input stream
- take as many bytes from the input stream as this number indicates to a memory buffer
- parse this buffer to regain **one** object
- if the input stream has more bytes continue with the next object